# Disappearing phone disk space when debugging

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.android, adb

I am writing an Android app using Xamarin Android. The problem is that each time I start debugging my app, space on my phones decreases more or less by the size of the app.

Anyone familiar with the problem? Do you know how to reclaim the space? Uninstalling the app does not help. Basically after some time I need to do factory reset to reclaim space.

Comment: Can you add some concrete evidence? Things such as the directories in question, the increase per deploy, and other items would help this question.

Comment: Actually I tried the most stupid thing now - restarting phone. And it worked. Space is back. It's just some temp data I guess...